# 2-normed square meaning

Tags: convex-optimization, least-squares

I heard $2$-normed square in a lecture talking about the objective function of least-squares.
What does the $2$ mean? I understand we take norm and square it, $2$ doesn't make sense to me.
$$\|Ax−B\|^2_2$$
In the above equation, I am referring to the subscript.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably referring to the case $p=2$ of a [$p$-norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_%28mathematics%29#p-norm).

Answer (score 1):

The $2$ in the subscript means that it's the two-norm or euclidean norm, meaning
that if we have, for example, an $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$, then:
$$\| x \|_2^2=\sqrt{\sum^n_{i=1} |x_i|^2}^2$$

The two norm is a special case of the $p$-norm so $\| x\|_p^2$ becomes
$$\| x\|_p^2 = \sqrt[p]{\sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|^p }^2.$$

Comment: Maybe this would be clearer if one says what $\|x\|^2_3$ would mean: $$ \large \sqrt[3]{ \sum_{i=1}^n |x|^3 }^2 $$ --- the square of the cube root of the sum of cubes of absolute values. $\qquad$

Comment: Good idea. But I assume that you meant to put two in the exponent and root.

Comment: Why assume that?  In $\|x\|_3^2$ I was deliberately using two different numbers as the subscript and superscript to show what their different roles are. $\qquad$

Comment: The question is about the 2-norm. :)

Comment: It was about the $2$-norm, and the question, if I understood correctly, is: What does the $2$ in the subscript mean?  So I explained what would change if you change that number. $\qquad$

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: @mhle Did you miss a $2$ in the first equation?

Comment: Abhishek: Do you mean in the root? A root is assumed to be a square root if nothing else is written by convention. Do you think it is ambiguous?